# postgresql join query matching null

Tags: postgresql

I can't make a request.

I have 3 tables.

I would like to have the following result:

services

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | service1 |
| 2 | service2 |

settings

| id | name | default_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | setting1 | 10 |
| 2 | setting2 | false |

services_settings

| id | service_id | setting_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 50 |

result

| service_id | final_value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 10 |

My query :

```
select
    services.id,
    coalesce(services_settings.value, settings.default_value)
from services
left join services_settings on services_settings.service_id = services.id
left join settings on settings.id = services_settings.setting_id and settings.name = 'setting1'
```

Thank you

Comment: JOIN clause and WHERE clause does the same things but logicaly differs: JOIN clause uses for jointing tables but WHERE clause uses for filtering records. So the condition settings.name = 'setting1' need to turn into into WHERE clause for claricity.
Also you can comment out WHERE clause for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CROSS JOIN` here

```
select 
    services.id,
    coalesce(services_settings.value, settings.default_value)
from services
left join services_settings on services_settings.service_id = services.id
cross join settings 
where settings.name = 'setting1'
```

[SQL online editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/ed26dcb474ea55cfa38e70c7183e3211/)

Comment: thank you !
I did not know cross join, but suddenly it still does not work it does not filter on settings.name.
replace line in services_settings: insert into services_settings values ​​(1, 1, 1, '50'), (2, 2, 2, true);

Comment: @jeyGey, post link with not working snippet

Comment: sorry. https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/176c6547f97badb5244bcac9f77419f4/
it puts the same value for any settings

Answer (score 0):

JOIN clause and WHERE clause does the same things but logicaly differs: JOIN clause uses for jointing tables but WHERE clause uses for filtering records.

So the condition settings.name = 'setting1' need to turn into into WHERE clause for claricity. Also you can comment out WHERE clause for troubleshooting.

```
select
    services.id,
    coalesce(services_settings.value, settings.default_value)
from services
left join services_settings on services_settings.service_id = services.id
left join settings on settings.id = services_settings.setting_id 
WHERE settings.name = 'setting1'
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work. 
I'm missing values ​​for services that don't have rows in the services_settings table.
the query filters too much.

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].